# Initialize array of derived objects like aggregate

Tags: c++, derived-class, array-initialization

Consider the following hierarchy of classes:

```
struct B {
    int i;
};

struct D : B {
    int j;
};
```

`B` is aggregate class, but `D` is not (because of base class existance).
Is there a way to initialize array of `D`'s like aggregate (i.e. without having user writen constructors)?

```
B b[] = {1, 2, 3}; // ok
D d[] = { ????? }; // is it possible?
```

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate: the linked question asks only about the 'why', whereas here it is about the workaround.

Comment: @davidhigh I think it's diplicate though. Because says it is not possible without user defined ctor (`the compiler will look for an appropriate constructor.`). Thank you for your attention.